# Solving trigonometric equation $\arctan y^2+\arctan x^2= π/4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given the equation $\arctan y^2+\arctan x^2= π/4$, I am asked to find $y$ given $x = 1/\sqrt2$. Even after reading the solution I'm still unsure of how to do it. In the solution, the following steps are displayed. I understand how the first line is obtained, but I don't understand how it goes from the first to the second. Where does the denominator come from? Should the first line not simply expand to the numerator of the second line?

[image]

Comment: Same problem (well not really a problem if you know you won't get a unique solution) as your previous question: do you know where $y$ lies (what interval)?

Comment: @BillO'Haran $y<0$ is also given.

Comment: There is trig. identity $$\tan (\alpha - \beta) = \dfrac{\tan \alpha - \tan \beta}{1 + \tan \alpha \tan \beta}.$$ In your case: $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{4}$, $\beta = \arctan\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***HINT:***

$$\tan(A\pm B)=\frac{\tan(A)\pm \tan(B)}{1\mp\tan(A)\tan(B)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the formula
$tan^{-1}A+tan^{-1}B= tan^{-1}\frac{A+B}{1-AB}$ we have,
$tan^{-1}\frac{x^2+y^2}{1-x^2y^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$
$\implies$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{1-x^2y^2}= tan\frac{\pi}{4}$
Can you solve it from here?